# VBA - range selection on repeating data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following sheet of data:
https://ethercalc.org/zeacfw3jskc3

The important thing about this data is that every column is repeated twice, one for type-A data, one for type-B. If there is no data in the first set of columns (up until revision), I want to create my range using the second rather than having the code fail. This is the code that attempts to do so:

```
Set w1 = wbk.Sheets("PositionsDB")
Set w2 = wbk.Sheets("Performance")
num_rows = w1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
'If there's no parentName column, we can't continue.
If w1.Rows(1).Find("portfolioName") Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'find first instance
Set f1 = w1.Rows(1).Find("portfolioName", lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not f1 Is Nothing Then
    'find second instance
    Set f2 = f1.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, w1.Columns.Count - f1.Column).Find("portfolioName", lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f2 Is Nothing Then
        'set range based on f2
        Set parentRange = w1.Range(f2.Offset(1, 0), w1.Cells(Rows.Count, f2.Column).End(xlUp))

    End If
End If
'If there's no Root level, how do we know where to start?
If parentRange.Find("Main") Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Debug.Print "test1"
Debug.Print parentRange.Width
Debug.Print parentRange.Height
Debug.Print "test2"

For Each parent In parentRange
    If Not dict.Exists(parent.Value) Then
        childCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(parentRange, parent.Value)
        Set childrenRange = parent.Offset(, 2).Resize(childCount, 1)
        dict.Add parent.Value, Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(childrenRange.Value))
    End If
Next
```

However, when I run this on using the data in the sheet, I get the following error:

```
Variable Required - Can't assign to this expression
For Each parent In parentRange
```

It is strange, because I get this exception without any of my Debug.Prints showing up in the immediate console. Is there an issue with my code?

Comment: `Parent` is a reserved word. Use some other term, e.g. `rng`.

Comment: Personally, I'd stick the two different ranges in two different arrays and loop through Entity ID column of one. If ISNULL(arr(i, whatevercolumnNumberEntityIdwas)) = True then arr2(i, whatevercolumnNumberEntityIdwas). I think you get the point. It would read a lot better I think. this is of course assuming the rows line up perfectly that is.

Comment: @BigBen *Parent is a reserved word*. Explain what you mean under *reserved*? This code works fine: `Dim Parent As Range: Set Parent = Range("A1"): MsgBox Parent.Address`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parent` is not declared. Thus, VBA considers it to be of type `Variant`. To loop through a range, you need an object, and not a variant:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim parent As Range

    For Each parent In Range("A1:A5")
        Debug.Print parent.Address
    Next parent

End Sub
```

If `parent` is declared as a `Variant`, it is casted to an object immediately by VBA:

[image]

To avoid all these kinds of problems - make sure that you always have `Option Explicit` on the top of your module/worksheet/class.

As a second thought, naming a variable `parent` is really not a great idea, but it works.

Comment: "To loop through a range, you need an object, and not a variant" - this is incorrect. Take off `As Range` and your code will still work, even though `parent` then is a `Variant`

Comment: @BigBen - see the screenshot.

Comment: in OP - `Parent` is not declared, but is **not** a `Variant` - there's a Compile error because of the confusion with the `Parent` property.

Comment: And even if OP had `Option Explicit`, if `Parent` was not defined then _the code would still not compile_. I.e. `Option Explicit` wouldn't catch an undefined variable, rather you'd have the same Compile error.

Comment: @BigBen - the idea of mentioning `Option Explicit` was that it would say immediately that there is a non-declared. But indeed, if the parent is non-declared, it is considered reserved word, hence getting the error from there.

Answer (score 2):

`Parent` is a reserved word. The `Parent` property of an object refers to that object's parent, e.g. a `Range` object has a `Worksheet` parent, and a `Worksheet` object has a `Workbook` parent.

The error:

> Variable required - Can't assign to this expression

arises because the [`For Each...Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/for-eachnext-statement) expects a *variable used to iterate through the elements of the collection or array*, and `Parent` is not a variable.

Use another name, e.g. `For each rng in parentRange`.

**EDIT:**

Note that this Compile error **specifically arises** because:

1. You've not declared `Parent`, and
2. This won't compile due to the confusion with the `Parent` property - `Parent` is **not** a `Variant` in this case - hence *"variable required, can't assign to this expression."*

As pointed out elsewhere, adding `Option Explicit` **and** `Dim parent as Range`, or even `Dim parent`, would eliminate the compile error, but might be misleading and is advised against.